# CPQ showing error 'Cannot read property replace of null'

Tags: cpq

I'm getting an issue while working on CPQ. I'm using a custom script for running CPQ, but custom script is not working even after making a lot of changes. It shows the below error. Even if the custom script is blank it shows this error. I tried to clone the custom script and use it but that is also not working. Can anybody please help me out with this?
[image: The image below shows this error every time I use QCP]

Comment: Since you're using a custom script, we are going to need to see the code to be able to pinpoint the issue. From the error message I can glean that there is a `replace` property trying to be read from a null object though.

Answer (score -1):

the Transpiled Code field on Custom Scrpit is null. that field will be only null when you have error in  your javascript, to know the error please check Apex jobs.